# flexbox and google pagespeed insights image optimization have conflicts?

Tags: css, flexbox, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I tried to optimized images on page https://terma-pl.com.ua/polotentsesushiteli-v-vannuyu using page speed insights, currently there are 3 images that mast be optimized. but google provides some strange images. They change their form after optimization, even if i set image width and height atributes and styles... If i remove flex from parent block, google provides normal images, what issue is this?

Fo example in flex block i have a p and img:

```
<div class="flexBlock">
<p>...</p>
<img src="/images/001Polotencesysh/colori-ral.jpg" width="250" height="250" 
style="width: 250px; height:250px; flex-basis: 250px;">
</div>

.flexBlock {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

The image before and after compression:

[image: before compression]

[image: after compression]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An initial setting on flex items is `flex-shrink: 1`. This means that items are permitted to shrink.

To disable this feature, add `flex-shrink: 0` to your inline style.

Comment: but why image optimizer on google page speed insights, care more about styles than about actual look of image and its sizes? Will they ever fix this behavior?